# Intersection of a sequence of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Is it possible to have a sequence of bounded closed intervals $I_{1},I_{2},...$ which are not necessarily nested, such that $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{N}I_{n}\neq\emptyset$$ for every $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}=\emptyset$$

Comment: Sure, $I_n=[n,\infty)$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr My guess is that the OP meant closed and bounded.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But he didn't say that... as the question is phrased, the proposed solution is reasonable.

Comment: Did you really mean what you wrote? Or did you mean that the intervals are closed and bounded?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was just responding to your answer when you deleted it - perhaps you could add the condition that some $I_n$ is compact in your answer because that could be interesting to some readers (using sequential compactness).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sure. I have deleted my answer. If the OP confirms my conjecture, then I will undelete it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $I_{n}=[0,\infty)$ is not closed

Comment: @MichaelBurr Good idea! I will do that.

Comment: @Jacob1215 Yes, it is closed (but not compact).  The complement is open because every point in the complement has an open interval contained in the complement.

Comment: I see. I should have phrased my question better then. Is it possible to find such a sequence which is compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, the OP (originally) did not specify if some $I_n$ is compact.  If some $I_n$ is compact, see Jose's answer.

Otherwise,
$$
I_n=[n,\infty)
$$
is a set of closed intervals satisfying the given condition since
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^NI_n=I_N\not=\emptyset,
$$
but whose intersection is empty.

Comment: Thank you! Compactness is an important specifier I will remember that

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you meant that each $I_n$ is closed and bounded, then the answer is negative, because then $\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^NI_n\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ *is* a decreasing sequence of non-empty closed and bounded intervals and therefore its intersection is non-empty. And$$\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=1}^NI_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n.$$

Comment: really ${}{}{}{}{}$? $I_n=[n,\infty)$

Comment: @GuyFsone Please read my comment to the question.

Comment: You really only need that one $I_n$ is compact, but this answer isn't wrong.

Comment: I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @Jacob1215 Then I suppose that I've answered your question.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos Thank you. I am still new to analysis, so forgive me if my question sounds trivial. But is it always true that the finite intersection is necessarily decreasing?

Comment: @Jacob1215 Yes. $A_1\supset A_1\cap A_2\supset A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\supset\cdots$

Comment: @MichaelBurr You answered by question completely. Thank you.

Comment: Clarifying the result that the intersection is nonempty - think about sequential compactness.  Suppose that $A_1\supset A_2\supset A_3\supset \cdots$.  Then, choose a point in each $A_i$, i.e., $a_i\in A_i$.  Then, there is some convergent subsequence due to sequential compactness.  The limit of this convergent subsequence must be in the infinite intersection.